# Convert an array of hashes to array of scalar values in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a reference to an array of hashes like this

```
[
    {
        'parameters'              => '',
        'default_init_for_config' => '1',
        'name'                    => 'CWG.BasicCmode.sim',
        'init'                    => 'config/CWG.BasicCmode.sim'
    },
    {
        'parameters'              => '',
        'default_init_for_config' => '0',
        'name'                    => 'CWG.BasicCmode.MFA.sim',
        'init'                    => 'config/CWG.BasicCmode.MFA.sim'
    },
    {
        'parameters'              => '',
        'default_init_for_config' => '0',
        'name'                    => 'NoInit',
        'init'                    => 'config/NoInit'
    },
    {
        'parameters'              => '',
        'default_init_for_config' => '0',
        'name'                    => '2Vsim.mcc',
        'init'                    => 'config/2Vsim.mcc'
    },
]
```

I want to extract the value of the key `name` alone and assign it to the same array.

I deleted all the other keys and got something like this:

```
[
    {
        'name' => 'CWG.BasicCmode.sim'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'CWG.BasicCmode.MFA.sim'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'NoInit'
    },
    {
        'name' => '2Vsim.mcc'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'FakeAFF_HA.sim'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'ISCSI.sim'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'CWG.ExtendedCmode.sim'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'CWG.BasicCmodeNonHA.sim'
    },
    {
        'name' => '2Vsim.FakeAFF.mcc'
    },
]
```

How to proceed now?

The output should be

```
[
    'CWG.Basicmode.sim',
    'CWG.BasicCmode.MFA.sim',
    'NoInit',
    ...
]
```

Comment: If you simply want an array of scalars, you could do: `$array_ref = [map { $_->{name} } @$array_ref]`

Comment: I have given final result as  [CWG.Basicmode.sim, NoInit,etc];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert an array of hashes to a plain array of scalar values to be constructed from the hashes from a given key, you can use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html). For example, assuming each hash has a `name` key, we can put the values of all these keys in a new arrayref like this:

```
my $new_array_ref = [map { $_->{name} } @$array_ref];
```

Comment: @Phoenix: Please don't solicit votes on Stack Overflow.